# Hiding enum element from JAX-WS generated WSDL

Tags: java, enums, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a enum class like blow. I'm using JAX-WS to generate WSDL, but I want to hide the DELETED enum from the client. Is there a way to do that? I tried @XmlTransient, but doen't work.

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@XmlEnum(String.class)
public enum StatusEnum {
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE,
    DELETED,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view,  if you for some reasons want to hide some enum entries from the client, then there are actually two enums, which are different by nature - "internal" and "client side". You can easily produce one from another right in your enum code:

```
public enum StatusEnum {
  ACTIVE(ClientStatusEnum.ACTIVE),
  INACTIVE(ClientStatusEnum.INACTIVE),
  DELETED(ClientStatusEnum.HIDDEN);

  private ClientStatusEnum clientStatusEnum;

  StatusEnum(ClientStatusEnum cse) {
    this.clientStatusEnum = cse;
  }

  public ClientStatusEnum getClientStatusEnum() {
    return clientStatusEnum;
  } 
}

@XmlEnum(String.class)
public enum ClientStatusEnum {
  ACTIVE,
  INACTIVE,
  HIDDEN;
}
```

Comment: does it mean client will still see the element named HIDDEN?

Comment: you can return `null` as well

Comment: I still don't get it. Does it mean I can use `StatusEnum.DELETED` for internal use, and client can use `ClientStatusEnum.HIDDEN`? What do you mean by returning `null`?